# CTL* and mu-calculus

Tags: lo.logic, model-checking, temporal-logic, mu-calculus

it is well known that the [modal $\mu$-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_%CE%BC-calculus) is one of the most expressive temporal logics for expressing properties of trees/graphs, and that [CTL*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTL%2a) is strictly less expressive than the $\mu$-calculus.

Here I would like to ask for an example of $\mu$-calculus formula, as simple as possible, that is not expressible in CTL*, and hopefully for an explaination of its meaning (fixed-point formulas quickly become unreadable).
Any good reference for a "concrete" simple example would also be great!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a path property that is not first-order expressible, e.g.
$$\nu x.p\wedge\Diamond\Diamond x$$
which says that there exists a path where the atomic proposition $p$ holds at every even position, and any valuation can be used on odd positions.

Comment: thanks a lot for this simple answer. Could you also suggest a reference supporting this example? Thank you again

Comment: Nice question & answer (+2). Have a look at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16186/6424. I gave the evenness example there too. Maybe some answer will refer to evenness, too.

Comment: @LORE81: the ``$p$ at even positions'' example is a classic, that you can find for instance in the paper by Wolper pointed by @DaveBall in his question.  It is not too difficult to prove directly by induction on LTL formulae; alternatively, you can construct the transition monoid and see that it is not aperiodic; finally you can try an Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé argument, though it's long to spell out in full detail.